# Trouble installing mod_ldap for Apache, requires a C SDK?

Tags: apache, module, ldap, openldap

The main website for building the mod_ldap and related modules for Apache require the config script to point to a "C SDK", I've installed OpenLDAP however I cannot seem to locate or find anywhere on the web if that provides an SDK.

The article is here for the module:
http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/mod_auth_ldap/mod_auth_ldap_apache2.html

Does OpenLDAP not provide a C SDK for this, or do I have to download the Iplanet C SDK or Mozilla C SDK to do this?

I had looked for the Iplanet one as linked, however the site was redone by Oracle and of course does not seem to have a direct link, I am having great trouble finding a suitable method of installing this Apache module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does OpenLDAP not provide a C SDK for this

Yes it does, and the link you cited already says so: 'If you installed Open LDAP server, you already have it.'